# Question about LKC LKV

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was answering probably a simple questions and I dont match the same result using the different method to solve that circuit below:

[image]

My 2 resolutions:

**KVL**:

\$\frac{30-V}{4}+2\cdot I_x-\frac{V}{6} = 0\$

\$I_x = \frac{30-V}{4} \Rightarrow 90-3V + 180-6V -V = 0\Rightarrow 10V = 270 \,\,\therefore\,\, \boxed{V = 27 V} \$

**KCL**:

\$ 30 = 4\cdot I_a + (I_a - I_b)\cdot 6\$

since: \$ I_a = I_x\$ and \$I_b = -2 \cdot I_x\$

then,

\$ 30 = 4Ix + 3I_x \cdot 6 \Rightarrow 30 = 22I_x\Rightarrow I_x = 30/22\$

\$ V = 30 - 4.I_x = 30 - 120/22 \Rightarrow \boxed{V \approx 24.5 V}\$

So, what I am missing on my analysis specially on KCL method?

Comment: You got an error in your math the correct solution is V = 270/11 (KVL) https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7B30%20-%20x%7D%7B4%7D%2B2%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B30-x%7D%7B4%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B6%7D%3D0

Comment: that's a big point. So Both methods are valid and the answer is aprox 24.5V?

Comment: Yes, the answer is approx 24.5V

Comment: sorry for my primary error. But I swear that I've repeated this math severals times.